# how to get character index in onTouch of webview

Tags: android, webview, ontouchlistener

I want to get the character index touched on the WebView. Please help me. Unfortunately I have not reached the answer so far

Comment: Please provide sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: @jorgeh: Unfortunately, I did not find any code despite a lot of searches